# updating product subtotal in cart contents

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I've trying to write my campaign plugin.
Here is the problem,

I want to update, `line_subtotal` and `line_total` in a product in `$cart_items`.

1- `woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal` is not really working.

2- I tried to redefine array's element by `cart_item_key`

```
                foreach($cartItems as $hash => $perProduct)
                { 
                    if($perProduct['product_id'] = $lastItemsProductId)
                    {
                        if($lastItemsQuantity > 1)
                        {
                            $lineSubtotal = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'line_subtotal');
                            $lineTotal = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'line_total');
                            $newQuantity = $lastItemsQuantity-1; 
                            
                            $lastItemInCart['line_subtotal'] = $newQuantity * $lastItemsPrice;
                            $lastItemInCart['line_total'] = $newQuantity * $lastItemsPrice;  
                            $cartItems[$lastItemsKey] = $lastItemInCart;  
 
                            WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
             
 
                            
                        } else {
                             
                        }
                    }
                     
                }
```

Also this function runs, in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action.

When i try it, with `woocommerce_get_cart_contents` filter, my cart empty itself .

3- The scenario :

When i add A product, (if is selected by system) and if quantity is more than 2, i want to make discount about this product.

Any helps ? Thanks.

**Here is the answer**

```
        /**
         * Add filter for order list 
         *
         * @param [int] $product_subtotal
         * @param [object] $product
         * @param [int] $quantity
         * @param [array] $cart
         * @return void
         */
        public function filterWoocommerceCartProductSubtotal($product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $cart) : string
        {
            $appliedCoupons  = $cart ? $cart->get_applied_coupons() : null;
            $cartCount = $cart ? count($cart->get_cart()) : 0;
            $cartItems = $cart->get_cart();
            $lastItemInCart = last($cartItems);
            $lastItemsProductId = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'product_id', data_get($lastItemInCart, 'product_id'));
            $lastItemsPrice = $lastItemInCart['data']->get_regular_price();
            $lastItemsQuantity = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'quantity');
            $lastItemsKey = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'key');
            
            if( in_array('3al2ode', $appliedCoupons)){  
                if($lastItemsQuantity > 1) {
                    if(@data_get($product,'id') == $lastItemsProductId)
                    {
                        $newSubTotal = 0;
                        $price = $product->get_price();  

                        $newQuantity = $lastItemsQuantity-1; 
                        $quantity = $newQuantity; 
                        $newSubTotal += $price * $quantity;
                
                        return $newSubTotal ? wc_price($newSubTotal) : $product_subtotal; 
                    }
                } 
                
            }  
            return $product_subtotal;
            
        }
```

The right, filter should be like;

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', [$this,'filterWoocommerceCartProductSubtotal'], 10, 4);`

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Is it the intention to adjust the price and the subtotal per line item (per product) in the cart based on the quantity of that product in the cart?

Comment: yes, need to update per product. also i added, solution thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        /**
         * Add filter for order list 
         *
         * @param [int] $product_subtotal
         * @param [object] $product
         * @param [int] $quantity
         * @param [array] $cart
         * @return void
         */
        public function filterWoocommerceCartProductSubtotal($product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $cart) : string
        {
            $appliedCoupons  = $cart ? $cart->get_applied_coupons() : null;
            $cartCount = $cart ? count($cart->get_cart()) : 0;
            $cartItems = $cart->get_cart();
            $lastItemInCart = last($cartItems);
            $lastItemsProductId = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'product_id', data_get($lastItemInCart, 'product_id'));
            $lastItemsPrice = $lastItemInCart['data']->get_regular_price();
            $lastItemsQuantity = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'quantity');
            $lastItemsKey = data_get($lastItemInCart, 'key');
            
            if( in_array('3al2ode', $appliedCoupons)){  
                if($lastItemsQuantity > 1) {
                    if(@data_get($product,'id') == $lastItemsProductId)
                    {
                        $newSubTotal = 0;
                        $price = $product->get_price();  

                        $newQuantity = $lastItemsQuantity-1; 
                        $quantity = $newQuantity; 
                        $newSubTotal += $price * $quantity;
                
                        return $newSubTotal ? wc_price($newSubTotal) : $product_subtotal; 
                    }
                } 
                
            }  
            return $product_subtotal;
            
        }
```

The right, filter should be like;

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', [$this,'filterWoocommerceCartProductSubtotal'], 10, 4);`

Answer (score 1):

As per your current scenario - When I add A product, (it is selected by the system) and if the quantity is more than 2, I want to make a discount on this product.

You should try this-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_add_discount',10, 1 );
function woocommerce_add_discount() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_qty = count($woocommerce->cart->get_cart());

    if($cart_qty > 2)
    {
        $percentage     = 0.5;

        $cart_subtotal  = $woocommerce->cart->get_subtotal() ?: 0;

        //$cart_total     = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
        //$shipping_total = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_total() ?: 0;
        //$tax_total      = $woocommerce->cart->get_taxes_total() ?: 0;
        //$grand_total    = $cart_total + $shipping_total + $tax_total;

        // Calculate the amount to reduce
        $discount = $cart_subtotal * $percentage;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Discount 50%', -$discount, true, '' );
    }
}
```

[image]

You can update/modify condition accordingly.

Comment: hello thanks for the reply. but there is cart total i need to prepare order list table update.

Comment: I also, updated my answer too.